Path.GetInvalidPathChars() apparently does not include all invalid characters
Consider following code:
public static bool isValidPath(string path) {
  return !Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Any(path.Contains);
}

var isValid = isValidPath("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\\"");

Yes, the path contains a double quote at the end: C:\Users\Public\Documents"
My code returns true for isValid.
But when I later try to create the path, I get an System.IO.IOException exception because the path is not correct.
Why does Path.GetInvalidPathChars() not return an "? I tried different ideas as well, like creating a DirectoryInfo object, but I get no exception. Path.GetFullPath returns the path with the double quote as well.
I don't want to create the path to check if it's valid, as it's creation is much further down the pipe.
I'm on Windows, and my app has to work on Unix as well


Why does Path.GetInvalidPathChars() not return an "?

Under *nix systems, it's perfectly valid to have a file named ". See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976050/1527466 +check out the answer below it.
As a result, you have to bite the bullet and handle exception cases. Your best bet is using the top answer from here but using DirectoryInfo in place of FileInfo: In C# check that filename is *possibly* valid (not that it exists)
As you said, it doesn't handle the lone " case. For this you'll have to consider the executing platform. On Windows, a string containing quotes is invalid and use of Path.GetFullPath can detect this. Or you may wish to do platform specific custom checks.
To check the platform, you can refer to here: How to check the OS version at runtime, e.g. on Windows or Linux, without using a conditional compilation statement
As for GetInvalidPathChars(), MS documentation states

The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names. The full set of invalid characters can vary by file system. For example, on Windows-based desktop platforms, invalid path characters might include ASCII/Unicode characters 1 through 31, as well as pipe (|) and null (\0).

IMO, this is akin to saying the function doesn't work as developers optimistically hope for, so will likely be insufficient. But even so, it is necessary to consider that even if it did return all invalid path characters, it does NOT define the full rules about what constitutes a valid path as that is always going to be OS dependent. The earlier links cover cases on Windows where certain words are reserved (like CON) which GetInvalidPathChars() will not cover. This is why you need to rely on exceptions.
You also say:

I don't want to create the path to check if it's valid, as it's creation is much further down the pipe.

Consider that a path string can be valid but does not mean or equate to it being creatable. It only means the path string is well-formed as to conform to what the OS could potentially use. For example, if it contains a drive letter or server name (M:\path\to\some\location or \\ServerName\path\to\some\location), while these are valid, you may not be able to create them later if M: doesn't exist or \\ServerName\ is unreachable or you have insufficient permissions. It probably is better to try to create the folder, catch any exception (deeming the path non-creatable). If you can create it, either delete it to allow later creation for your downstream process having deemed it creatable, or just leave it and use downstream.
EDIT:
You may wish to try Path.GetFullPath(path) as this will throw an exception if invalid characters have been used. It processes a relative path to an absolute path, or leaves unchanged if an absolute path was provided.
Here's a crude starting point which also has an out parameter to return an absolute path, which may or may not differ. In the cases where the method returns true, you'd want to use the absolute path:
public static bool IsValidAndCreatablePath(string proposedPath, out string adjustedPath, bool reuseExistingPaths = false)
{
    // default the output arg
    adjustedPath = proposedPath;

    if (proposedPath == null || proposedPath.Length == 0) return false;

    try
    {
        // Path.GetFullPath does catch any illegal characters in the path. 
        string fullProposedPath = Path.GetFullPath(proposedPath);

        adjustedPath = fullProposedPath;

        // use a DirectoryInfo for further steps
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fullProposedPath);

        if (!reuseExistingPaths)
        {
            if (di.Exists) return false;
        }

        if (!di.Exists)
        {
            // create path - throws IOException if it doesn't work, so nothing to delete
            di.Create();

            // created, so delete - throws IOException, DirectoryNotFoundException, UnauthorisedAccessException
            di.Delete();
        }

        // must be valid
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // consume - in practice you may wish to catch and rethrow specific exceptions
    }
    return false;
}


I tried GetFullPath and DirectoryInfo as well, they did not care about the single double quote at the end. So my team decided that we just accept it, and let it crash (aka catch the exception) when creating the path later on, printing it out so the user may find the error. Thank you though!
